# Error handling (dividing by zero)

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm working on a project where I am plotting orbital motion of satellites given certain parameters. The equation I'm plotting is the following:

```
R=r/(1+e*np.cos(phi))
```

where `r` is the radius of the orbit if it was circular, `e` is the eccentricity of the orbit, and `phi` is the cylindrical angle from `0` to `2*pi`. I've been plotting different values of `e` and if I let `e==1`, I receive this message from Python:

> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide

which occurs when `phi==pi`.

What I'm wondering is what can I do to error check in my code and tell Python if you receive this kind of error, just skip that calculation and go onto the next one?

Comment: Maybe you should just be a little less eccentric in your orbiting.

Comment: By the way, to dups complainers: this is not really a ``ZeroDivisionError`` issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to avoid this, would be to do an IF statement before, and if phi is equal to pi don't go into the calculation. I don't think you should intentionally go into errors when they are this predictable.

To make the subject a bit clearer, in my opinion, try/catch should only be resorted to, if the error cannot be predicted.
I dont agree with the use of errors as acceptable software behaviour or design pattern.

```
if(phi != PI):
    R=r/(1+e*np.cos(phi))
```

or, if you prefer, make a special behaviour if phi == PI

Comment: +1 Since `e=1` represents a parabolic orbit, the distance `R` does indeed go to infinity as `phi` approaches pi.